# Decode binary file in python3 does not work

Tags: python-3.x, file, binary, decode

Im trying to decode a binary file.

Here is a sniped from the file:

```
Content-Length: 122092
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x80\x00\x03\x00`FFTMm\x02\xd2u\x00\x00\x00\xec\x00\x00\x00\x1cGDEF\x00\'\x023\x00\x00\x01\x08\x00\x00\x00\x1eOS/2\x886z\x01\x00\x00\x01(\x00\x00\x00`cmap\xc9\x03\xa0\xac\x00\x00\x01\x88\x00\x00\x02\xc2gasp\xff\xff\x00\x03\x00\x00\x04L\x00\x00\x00\x08glyf\x05.G/\x00\x00\x04T\x00\x01\xb1\xechead\t\xe6\x15\x97\x00\x01\xb6@\x00\x00\x006hhea\x0e\xf9\n(\x00\x01\xb6x\x00\x00\x00$hmtx:b\x13<\x00\x01\xb6\x9c\x00\x00\x08\xaaloca\x18\xce\x84\xc4\x00\x01\xbfH\x00\x00\x04\\maxp\x02\x96\x02\x1c\x00\x01\xc3\xa4\x00\x00\x00

...

\xf52\xb5{ \x9e\xa8V\xb1\x93\x89m8\xca\xca\xdf\x14K\xb1g\x1dX3\xe4\xa3\xa5e\x195>\x9a&\x15\xa8\xa5eZ\xfe\x00c\x80\x06\xef\xb6\x18M\x06\x9d\xc1\xc0\xeb\x95\xc5\x8e\xce?\xcdh\xbetV\xfb\xbe\x99\x03\xbb\x
```

I used following code to decode the file:

```
file_data = open('font2.txt', 'rb').read()
file_data = file_data.decode('utf-16')
print(file_data)
```

Unfortunately it seems that it will not be decoded correctly. The output of decode is the same as in the encoded file.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve it?

I am grateful for any hints. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a binary file as plain text using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859552/reading-a-binary-file-as-plain-text-using-python)

Comment: First of all, do you know how the file was encoded?

Comment: @AdamStrauss: Unfortunately no
Same output like in the input file.

@sophros: No, I don`t know. But maybe this information helps:


Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Dec 2019 07:46:05
Content-Length: 122092
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: Closed